How to Allow all NATed traffic from iptables firewall via pfsense (gateway)
I have an iptables firewall (machine 1) and a centos 7 based gateway (machine 2), which is having 2 interfaces (machine-2:int-1) from WAN [/30] and (machine-2:int-2) is LAN [/28] one of the static IP provided by ISP. Now this setup is working fine, machine-1:LAN-subnets are doing iptables based NATing and machine-1:LAN-subnet-int's gateway is machine-2's:int-2. All routes for NATed IPs gateway are set as iptables firewall.
  LAN
   ^
   |
   |
FIREWALL (NAT) --> Other int's *-- IPTABLES
   ^
   |
   |
GATEWAY (no NAT) *-- PFSense
   ^
   |
   | 
  WAN (ISP)

Now I would like to replace the CentOS based gateway with PFSense. As soon as I replaced the Gateway machine with PFSense, NATed addresses are not passing thru. I tweaked the NAT outbounds rules, disabled it. Still I could not make this happen. I need to make rules and routing in PFSense, that allows all the traffic from LAN to WAN as is (no NATing - since iptables firewall is taking care of it). Please suggest.

Is your new gateway set to be on same subnet as your firewall's NAT-ed subnet? this is first step, next check routing tables on the firewall computer. you might want to edit your post with IP configuration of your gateway, firewall and LAN

@metablaster, Yes both new gateway and firewall are on same subnet. Now, I got into trouble of getting in loop after setting static routing, the firewall NATed IP’s gateway is this PFSense gateway and PFSense default gateway is WAN. Now, nated packets loop around this gateway and firewall, going nowhere. I must be missing something!
